# Spring boot works in Eclipse, not in docker

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, docker

I've been working on a little spring boot app using docker-compose. I've got a container with the web app and one with the database. For development/debugging I've been launching just the database container using docker-compose and running the spring boot app in debug mode in Eclipse. So far, so good.

Then I try to run the whole thing using docker-compose. This is my yml file and log output below (some names have been changed to protect the innocent)...for testing the docker part I've mapped the jar file rather than rebuild the docker image every time.

```
version: '3'
```

services:

```
    myapp-service:
            image: myapp-service
            env_file: 
               - common.env
            ports:
               - 8080:8080
                 volumes:
                 - "./target/myapp-service.jar:/myapp-service.jar"
            depends_on: 
               - database

    database:
            image: mongo
            env_file:
               - common.env
            volumes:
               - "./init-mongo.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.js:ro"
            ports:
               - "27017-27019:27017-27019"
```

I have a custom login form, and running in Eclipse it works just fine. This is what I get when I run the whole thing in docker and navigate to the web page:

```
 myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.083 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.083 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login", parameters={}
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.084 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.sammckee.data.controller.LoginController#login()
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.085 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.085 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : View name 'login', model {}
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.086 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : Forwarding to [/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp]
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.092 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@49e79d09
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.092 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.093 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.093 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.093 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.093 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.093 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.093 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.093 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@6c18ca17. A new one will be created.
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.093 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.093 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.093 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.093 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/logout'
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.093 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.093 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.093 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.093 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'PUT /logout'
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.093 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.093 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout'
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.093 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.093 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.093 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'POST /login'
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.093 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.093 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : pathInfo: both null (property equals)
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.093 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : queryString: both null (property equals)
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.093 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : requestURI: arg1=/; arg2=/error (property not equals)
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.093 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : saved request doesn't match
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.093 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.093 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.094 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@48fd2a32: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 172.30.0.1; SessionId: 7F4F9718EE23E9AA0244329F374437D3; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.094 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.094 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.094 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.094 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.094 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.094 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.097 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.097 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.097 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.097 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
myapp-service_1  | 2020-05-04 00:20:27.097 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Any thoughts on what I might be missing? Again, it works fine in Eclipse. Sorry for the long log text--I wanted to make sure I was giving all the info necessary.

Edit/addendum:
When I navigate to the web app I see this:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon May 04 00:20:27 GMT 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp
```

My DAOs derive from a class that connects to the database like this:

```
String client_url = "mongodb://" + dbuser + ":" + dbpassword + "@" + hostName + ":" + 27017 + "/"
                        + databaseName;
```

...where the host name, database, user and password are passed in by environment variables.

For the hostname I'm passing in "database" because that's the container name--that's how it should work in the container, right? When I run it in Eclipse I pass in "localhost" for the host name because the database container exposes the same port number to the local environment, and it works fine. I sort of expect to see database error messages if it's a problem with my mongo connection, but maybe not.

Edit/Addendum 2: 
It definitely looks like there's something Springy I'm doing wrong. I made a little shell script to set the environment variables and run the jar file standalone in bash, outside the container, and it works as expected. Inside the docker container, I get errors. This is the part of the log that catches my eye:

```
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'loginController'
 s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.myapp.bank.controller.LoginController#login()
 .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Arguments: []
 o.s.w.s.v.InternalResourceViewResolver   : View with key [login] served from cache
 o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
 o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'login'; URL [/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp]] 
 o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : View name 'login', model {}
 o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'requestDataValueProcessor'
 o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : Forwarding to [/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp]
 o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@70ad1909
  w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
 o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND, headers={masked}
  o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
```

Edit/Addendum 3:
Still stumped. What I have confirmed is that I can copy the jar file to other places, and it runs fine there, serves up JSPs as expected and does everything I want it to do. So it seems to me the jar file itself must be okay. I'm mystified by what might be different when it's inside docker.

Comment: What is the behavior when you try to access the web application?
Also in your spring boot properties file how do you connect to the database?

Comment: Adding edit/addendum to post...

Comment: First in order to determine where the problem relies, I would suggest running the jar locally, but not from Eclipse. Just open a CMD and java -jar myapp-service.jar or whatever Entrypoint you used in you Dockerfile. Is it working like this? If not it means that something is not defined well in your Spring configuration. If it does work then it is something Docker related. Either way you should provide more details like project structure, properties file and so on.

Comment: Running from bash terminal worked (once I got all the environment variables set), so making progress. Thanks! Gotta tinker a little more now and figure out what's different in my container. I'll let you know what I find. 

Thanks so much.

Comment: Based on you reply, the fact that it works separately and that there are no database connection errors I believe there is something configured incorrectly in the spring part. It could be the way it resolves the web files, the mappings to the actual resources.

Comment: That sounds right. Added edit above.